# Bidirectional Communication Async with ZeroMQ

Tags: python, c++, sockets, client-server, zeromq

I am understanding the [different socket and patterns types](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket) because I am interested in having several clients talking to each other in a collaborative way, having maybe a server broker or middleware .Will be useful to receive and forward messages beetween entities related.

My study/situation case is the following:
I've want to denote the workflow via step numbers interaction in my diagram. I hope not to be inconvenient with my diagram, I only refer it to better illustrate my situation

[image]

What it would be an appropriate pattern to achieve bidirectional, asynchronous messages between two client nodes to exchange messages?

Because all of this ... I have been reading and the `ZMQ_ROUTER` and `ZMQ_DEALER` sockets they seem to be a good option because the ongoing and incoming routing strategy.

I understand that the process of queuing each received message from all peers connected  (in `ZMQ_DEALER`)  and and each message sent is round-robined among all connected peers

What mean round-robined in this context?

With the `ZMQ_ROUTER` happen something similar in relation to incoming routing strategy ...

I have been testing the [Shared Queue Dealer and Router sockets samples](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Shared-Queue-DEALER-and-ROUTER-sockets) but the process is synchronous, because  I've used it in a `REQ-ROUTER-DEALER-REP` set up but in that case the `REQ -> ROUTER` send does not target a particular handler on the other side, it just goes to an arbitrary one and the ROUTER makes sure the reply goes back to the original sender.

I think that my situation is similar [to this Jake's question](https://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2018-February/032284.html) in zeromq mailing list

The broker approach `ROUTER-DEALER`  ... is right think about it? 
Or the communication may be client to client directly?

I ask all this  with the order to share my considerations and learn and receive some orientation of you ZMQ people in relation to the appropriate pattern to achieve bidirectional, asynchronous messages between two client nodes.

Comment: Check the boost asio chat server example in c++. It supports multiple clients  and works in duplex mode as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server code you want to run a `zmq_router` and `bind` it to a well known port.

Each client app should then create a `zmq_dealer` socket and `connect` to the ip and port the router bound to. Before connecting you may wish to set an id on the socket that can be used to identify each client.

To ensure clients send messages to the correct place then we need to append the id of the client they wish to speak to as the first message part to allow it to route to the correct client through the router.

You will only hit issues with round robin if you do multiple connects per `dealer` socket i.e. connecting directly to other client dealer sockets.

Comment: It's something like this first figure [Asynchronous Client/Server](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Asynchronous-Client-Server-Pattern) ?  My server would only `bind()` to a single known port and only that port would be linked to the different N  existing clients ?

Comment: I have been reading about of your recommendation, and I found this [The DEALER to ROUTER Combination](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-DEALER-to-ROUTER-Combination)  In my case, is possible that I need emulate or implement REQ/REP in each client? I haven't clear this ...

Comment: The Async client/server is what you are looking for. Bind to a single known port and then connect all clients only to that port on the server. Then use client ids to send messages async between different clients.

Comment: This Load balancing message broker, attach the identity client ... and send them to workers .. http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter3#A-Load-Balancing-Message-Broker  This is some good roadmap?

Comment: @bgarcial It can be if you need the extra performance. I have used Dealer->Router->Dealer patterns before with success without any extra need for other worker sockets.

Comment: Hi friend. I again. Let me contact to you please. When a  `DEALER `client sends [X] to a `ROUTER`, the router receives [I, X] where I is the identity of the sender. When a `ROUTER` sends a message [I, X], the connected `DEALER` socket with identity I receives message [X]. Until here all it's OK .. 1 of 2

Comment: How to can I in the `ZMQ_ROUTER` side, when I receive a message from one peer `ZMQ_DEALER`, send this message to another `ZMQ_DEALER` peer? I will need that the router know both identities of `ZMQ_DEALER` peers  previously, store them and send the message using these identities ? I have this question just in case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289072/zmq-dealer-router-communication

Comment: In the past I have sent a header frame that tells the router the destination id and then get the router to forward this on again.

Comment: How to can I send that header frame? I am using  `s_send` in the `ZMQ_DEALER`  which receive the socket name and the message body as a parameters.  My doubt is how to a `DEALER` figure the id or id's of the other `DEALERS` destination?  This should make on the `DEALERS`?  Can you orient me with some code sample please? if this is not disturb for you of course

Comment: Look into multipart messages - http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter2#toc9